# Gas Optimisation of updating/reading struct in mapping

Tags: solidity, gas, storage

I'm trying to shave off a few thousand GAS from a transaction. I have the following struct in a mapping:

```
struct Data{
    uint8[4] a
    uint8[4] b
    bytes5 z; 
}
mapping(uint => Data) public data;
```

example update function:

```
function update(uint _x, uint8 _y, bytes5 _z) public returns (bool){
    data[_x].a[_y]++;
    data[_x].z= _z;

    return (data[_x].a[_y] < data[_x].b[_y]);
}
```

The function needs to update z, increment one of the values of a, and compare it to the corresponding value of b. returning a bool of whether or not the latter is greater than the former.

Just updating the above seems to cost about 40,000 GAS, (not including the read/comparison). it seems  high given its all much less than 256 bits. I've played around with a few things but can't seem to get the gas costs any lower.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Share the code of how you are trying to update them